# Trouble installing Angular-hint

Tags: angularjs, npm

Recently I found this article (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/11/06/exploring-angular-1.3-angular-hint.html), it seems like Angular-hint is very useful for developer. So, I try to install Angular-hint with this command:

```
npm install angular-hint
```

During the installation, I see angular-hint folder with files created in `node_modules` folder. But at the end of installation, everything is gone. In the command window, I saw this:

```
E:\www\angularjs\angular-hint\node_modules\angular-hint\node_modules\angular-hint-log\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\50d41671-che-browserify-4-2-3-package-tgz.lock.STALE'
File exists: C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\50d41671-che-browserify-4-2-3-package-tgz.lock.STALE
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular-hint"
npm ERR! cwd E:\www\angularjs\angular-hint
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\50d41671-che-browserify-4-2-3-package-tgz.lock.STALE
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I get it properly installed?

Comment: The message says: "Move it away, and try again.". Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I tried. But it doesn't help. I try on other PC, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sudo npm install angular-hint --save-dev
```

we use --save-dev to make it a dev dependency
if that doesn't work for you, try bower!

You can use bower.

```
$ sudo npm install -g bower
$ bower search angular-hint
$ search results:
    angular-hint git://github.com/angular/angular-hint.git
    angular-hint2 git://github.com/mallowigi/angular-hint.git

$ bower init
$ bower install angular-hint --save
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get Angular-hint installed using bower and load `hint.js` into my app. However, it shows error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Same problem here: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Glenn's answer. After installing **angular-hint** with **bower** you have to go to the created directory and run the following commands:

```
$ npm install
```

to install the dependencies required by angular-hint and

```
$ npm run build
```

to generate the `dist` directory with the final `hint.js` file.

Alternatively, you can just use [angular-hint-bower](https://github.com/welbornio/angular-hint-bower).